# Does unemployment compensation count as AGI?

Tags: united-states, taxes, unemployment, pennsylvania

Does unemployment compensation count as part of your Annual Gross Income?
(This is related to [my other question about writing off getting braces on my taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/should-i-pay-off-my-braces-all-at-once-so-that-i-can-write-them-off-this-year-as))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unemployment compensation is considered income and taxed as such.  In fact, you have the option of withholding federal taxes form unemployment compensation.

Comment: This reminds me that I need to figure out the impact of not withholding on my taxes for 2010. Oy.