# Can a check used for medical expenses be written off if it is written in the current year and clears in the following year?

Tags: taxes, healthcare, pennsylvania

I am considering writing a check to pay off my braces all at once since it is an [amount larger than 7.5% of my income](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/should-i-pay-off-my-braces-all-at-once-so-that-i-can-write-them-off-this-year-as).

However it is getting very close to the end of the year; if I write the check in 2010, and the check clears in 2011; will the payment still be considered part of 2010 on my tax write-off since I dated the check as 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to IRS [Publication 502](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p502/ar02.html#en_US_publink1000178852):

> If you pay medical expenses by check, the day you mail or deliver the check generally is the date of payment.

The quoted text can be found under the section titled *What Expenses Can You Include This Year?*

Comment: Protip: Get a proof of mailing or send certified mail in case of an audit.